# Faster parsing of numbers on .NET

Tags: c#, performance, parsing, f#

I have written two functions that convert a string of whitespace-separated integers into an int array. The first function uses `Substring` and then applies `System.Int32.Parse` to convert the substring into an `int` value:

```ml
let intsOfString (s: string) =
  let ints = ResizeArray()
  let rec inside i j =
    if j = s.Length then
      ints.Add(s.Substring(i, j-i) |> System.Int32.Parse)
    else
      let c = s.[j]
      if '0' <= c && c <= '9' then
        inside i (j+1)
      else
        ints.Add(s.Substring(i, j-i) |> System.Int32.Parse)
        outside (j+1)
  and outside i =
    if i < s.Length then
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0' <= c && c <= '9' then
        inside i (i+1)
      else
        outside (i+1)
  outside 0
  ints.ToArray()
```

The second function traverses the characters of the string in-place accumulating the integer without creating a temporary substring:

```ml
let intsOfString (s: string) =
  let ints = ResizeArray()
  let rec inside n i =
    if i = s.Length then
      ints.Add n
    else
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0' <= c && c <= '9' then
        inside (10*n + int c - 48) (i+1)
      else
        ints.Add n
        outside(i+1)
  and outside i =
    if i < s.Length then
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0' <= c && c <= '9' then
        inside (int c - 48) (i+1)
      else
        outside (i+1)
  outside 0
  ints.ToArray()
```

Benchmarking on space-separated integers 1 to 1,000,000, the first version takes 1.5s whereas the second version takes 0.3s.

Parsing such values can be performance critical so leaving 5x performance on the table by using temporary substrings can be undesirable. Parsing integers is easy but parsing other values such as floating point numbers, decimals and dates is considerably harder.

So, are there built-in functions to parse directly from a substring within a string (i.e. using the given start and length of a string) in order to avoid generating a temporary string? If not, are there any libraries that provide efficient functions to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions instead of using Substring? A compiled regular expression can be much faster than string operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you explain how a regular expression can be used to parse a string into an array of ints?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently and couldn't find any when I searched, had to write the decimal parsing code myself. It's not as hard as you might think as the Decimal class has a constructor that takes a scale factor so you can do pretty much the same as integer parsing and just keep track of where the decimal point is. Dates weren't too hard either, however I did have tight control over the formats in both cases. I wouldn't want to write general parsing code...

Comment: Such data always comes from a file (or other I/O). Write a benchmark to include the I/O and you will see you're optimizing something that consumes less than  1% of the time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That is incorrect. Reading this data from disk takes 0.2-1.5s depending whether or not it is in the disk cache. And it could come in over Infiniband...

Comment: @HenkHolterman It might be less than 1% overall but it could still be a bottleneck. In my case I have thousands of messages coming in per second over the network, each containing lots of decimals, that have to be processed in a strict order limiting the amount I can parse and process in parallel. I made a similar change to my parsing logic recently and doubled my overall throughput...

Comment: @HenkHolterman - if processing this is a problem you should modify the program which is creating the file - for example you could just copy the byte representation into a file and then read it straight back in to memory without any conversion

Comment: Why are you using textual data instead of binary data in high performance situations?

Comment: @CodeInChaos Might not have control over that - in my case I had to interface with multiple already existing systems that they wouldn't let me change...

Comment: There are no built-in functions for this that I know of. I think you'll have a hard time finding a more general parsing lib that matches the speed of your hand-rolled function.

Comment: I have a really bad advice. Have you considered FParsec?

Comment: @JonHarrop: [runParserOnString and friends](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.runParserOnString) seem to be relevant. And they have plenty of primitive parsers for numbers.

Comment: I've rolled back Henk's change to my question because this has nothing to do with file-io and is equally applicable to C#.

Comment: @pad FParsec's `pFloat` just calls `System.Double.Parse` so it is probably slow too.

Comment: I don't know of better functions in the BCL, but this is a classic example of being able to optimize for a specific use case. The BCL functions are very general.

Comment: Funny, [Marc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) blogged about [something similar](http://marcgravell.blogspot.ch/2013/11/allocaction-allocation-allocation.html) not long ago.

Answer (score 8):

`System.Int32.Parse` is slowlest, because it used `CultureInfo`, `FormatInfo` and etc; and performance reason is not in the temporary strings.

Code from reflection:

```
private unsafe static bool ParseNumber(ref char* str, NumberStyles options, ref Number.NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo numfmt, bool parseDecimal)
{
    number.scale = 0;
    number.sign = false;
    string text = null;
    string text2 = null;
    string str2 = null;
    string str3 = null;
    bool flag = false;
    string str4;
    string str5;
    if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        text = numfmt.CurrencySymbol;
        if (numfmt.ansiCurrencySymbol != null)
        {
            text2 = numfmt.ansiCurrencySymbol;
        }
        str2 = numfmt.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        str3 = numfmt.NumberGroupSeparator;
        str4 = numfmt.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
        str5 = numfmt.CurrencyGroupSeparator;
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        str4 = numfmt.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        str5 = numfmt.NumberGroupSeparator;
    }
    int num = 0;
    char* ptr = str;
    char c = *ptr;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!Number.IsWhite(c) || (options & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite) == NumberStyles.None || ((num & 1) != 0 && ((num & 1) == 0 || ((num & 32) == 0 && numfmt.numberNegativePattern != 2))))
        {
            bool flag2;
            char* ptr2;
            if ((flag2 = (((options & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign) == NumberStyles.None) ? false : ((num & 1) == 0))) && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
            {
                num |= 1;
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (flag2 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                {
                    num |= 1;
                    number.sign = true;
                    ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c == '(' && (options & NumberStyles.AllowParentheses) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 1) == 0)
                    {
                        num |= 3;
                        number.sign = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((text == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text)) == null) && (text2 == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text2)) == null))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        num |= 32;
                        text = null;
                        text2 = null;
                        ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
    }
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || ((options & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None && ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'))))
        {
            num |= 4;
            if (c != '0' || (num & 8) != 0)
            {
                if (num2 < 50)
                {
                    number.digits[(IntPtr)(num2++)] = c;
                    if (c != '0' || parseDecimal)
                    {
                        num3 = num2;
                    }
                }
                if ((num & 16) == 0)
                {
                    number.scale++;
                }
                num |= 8;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((num & 16) != 0)
                {
                    number.scale--;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char* ptr2;
            if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 16) == 0 && ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str4)) != null || (flag && (num & 32) == 0 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str2)) != null)))
            {
                num |= 16;
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowThousands) == NumberStyles.None || (num & 4) == 0 || (num & 16) != 0 || ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str5)) == null && (!flag || (num & 32) != 0 || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str3)) == null)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
        }
        c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
    }
    bool flag3 = false;
    number.precision = num3;
    number.digits[(IntPtr)num3] = '\0';
    if ((num & 4) != 0)
    {
        if ((c == 'E' || c == 'e') && (options & NumberStyles.AllowExponent) != NumberStyles.None)
        {
            char* ptr3 = ptr;
            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
            char* ptr2;
            if ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
            {
                c = *(ptr = ptr2);
            }
            else
            {
                if ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                {
                    c = *(ptr = ptr2);
                    flag3 = true;
                }
            }
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                int num4 = 0;
                do
                {
                    num4 = num4 * 10 + (int)(c - '0');
                    c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
                    if (num4 > 1000)
                    {
                        num4 = 9999;
                        while (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                        {
                            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
                if (flag3)
                {
                    num4 = -num4;
                }
                number.scale += num4;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr = ptr3;
                c = *ptr;
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            if (!Number.IsWhite(c) || (options & NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite) == NumberStyles.None)
            {
                bool flag2;
                char* ptr2;
                if ((flag2 = (((options & NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign) == NumberStyles.None) ? false : ((num & 1) == 0))) && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
                {
                    num |= 1;
                    ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (flag2 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                    {
                        num |= 1;
                        number.sign = true;
                        ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (c == ')' && (num & 2) != 0)
                        {
                            num &= -3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((text == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text)) == null) && (text2 == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text2)) == null))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            text = null;
                            text2 = null;
                            ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
        }
        if ((num & 2) == 0)
        {
            if ((num & 8) == 0)
            {
                if (!parseDecimal)
                {
                    number.scale = 0;
                }
                if ((num & 16) == 0)
                {
                    number.sign = false;
                }
            }
            str = ptr;
            return true;
        }
    }
    str = ptr;
    return false;
}
public static int Parse(string s)
{
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

internal unsafe static int ParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
{
    byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[1 * 114 / 1];
    Number.NumberBuffer numberBuffer = new Number.NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
    int result = 0;
    Number.StringToNumber(s, style, ref numberBuffer, info, false);
    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        if (!Number.HexNumberToInt32(ref numberBuffer, ref result))
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Number.NumberToInt32(ref numberBuffer, ref result))
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private unsafe static void StringToNumber(string str, NumberStyles options, ref Number.NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo info, bool parseDecimal)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("String");
    }
    fixed (char* ptr = str)
    {
        char* ptr2 = ptr;
        if (!Number.ParseNumber(ref ptr2, options, ref number, info, parseDecimal) || ((ptr2 - ptr / 2) / 2 < str.Length && !Number.TrailingZeros(str, (ptr2 - ptr / 2) / 2)))
        {
            throw new FormatException(Environment.GetResourceString("Format_InvalidString"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. @JonHarrop should measure the performance of using his simpler int parser on a substring version, just to make sure the root cause of the 5x is fully understood.

Comment: It's probably a bit of both. In my similar situation I made performance gains from custom integer parsing (because I could assume a single format) and from not cutting up my input string.

Comment: @fmr "@JonHarrop should measure the performance of using his simpler int parser on a substring version, just to make sure the root cause of the 5x is fully understood". Split into substrings takes 0.7s. Split into substrings and map my fast int parser over them takes 0.99s. There are other forces at work here though.

Comment: Ok - then using a "full" parser adapted to work on arbitrary positions in the input string could get you to 2-3x the simple fast parser. Could be worth checking the Mono System.*.Parse and "fixing" their input.

Answer (score 5):

I've written this one for doubles, that doesn't create a temporary substring. It's meant to be used inside a JSON parser so it limits itself to how doubles can be represented in JSON according to http://www.json.org/.

It's not optimal yet because it requires you to know where the number begins and ends (`begin` and `end` parameters), so you'll have to traverse the length of the number twice to find out where it ends. It's still around 10-15x faster than `double.Parse` and it could be fairly easily modified that it finds the `end` inside the function which is then returned as an `out` parameter to know where you have to resume parsing the main string.

Used like so:

```
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("1", 0, 1, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("2.0", 0, 3, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("3.5", 0, 3, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("-4.5", 0, 4, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("50.06", 0, 5, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("1000.65", 0, 7, out j);
Parsers.TryParseDoubleFastStream("-10000.8600", 0, 11, out j);
```

Code can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/3010984 (would be too lengthy to post here).

And `StandardFunctions.IgnoreChar` is for my purpose as simple as:

```
public static bool IgnoreChar(char c)
{
  return c < 33;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Paste all this code into C# and call `Test()`. This is as close as you can get to operating directly on the string array to parse numbers using C#. It is built for speed, not elegance. The `ParseInt` and `ParseFloat` function were created for an OpenGL graphics engine to import vectors from text-based 3d models. Parsing floats is a significant bottleneck in that process. This was as fast as I could make it.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    private void Test()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int iterations = 1000;

        // Build a string of 1000000 space separated numbers
        for (var n = 0; n < iterations; n++)
        {
            if (n > 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            sb.Append(n.ToString());
        }

        string numberString = sb.ToString();

        // Time the process
        sw.Start();
        StringToInts(numberString, iterations);
        //StringToFloats(numberString, iterations);
        sw.Stop();
        long proc1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("iterations: {0} \t {1}ms", iterations, proc1);
    }

    private unsafe int[] StringToInts(string s, int length)
    {
        int[] ints = new int[length];
        int index = 0;
        int startpos = 0;

        fixed (char* pStringBuffer = s)
        {
            fixed (int* pIntBuffer = ints)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < s.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (s[n] == ' ' || n == s.Length - 1)
                    {
                        if (n == s.Length - 1)
                            n++;
                        // pIntBuffer[index++] = int.Parse(new string(pStringBuffer, startpos, n - startpos));
                        pIntBuffer[index++] = ParseInt((pStringBuffer + startpos), n - startpos); 
                        startpos = n + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ints;
    }

    private unsafe float[] StringToFloats(string s, int length)
    {
        float[] floats = new float[length];
        int index = 0;
        int startpos = 0;

        fixed (char* pStringBuffer = s)
        {
            fixed (float* pFloatBuffer = floats)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < s.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (s[n] == ' ' || n == s.Length - 1)
                    {
                        if (n == s.Length - 1)
                            n++;

                        pFloatBuffer[index++] = ParseFloat((pStringBuffer + startpos), n - startpos); // int.Parse(new string(pStringBuffer, startpos, n - startpos));
                        startpos = n + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return floats;
    }

    public static unsafe int ParseInt(char* input, int len)
    {
        int pos = 0;           // read pointer position
        int part = 0;          // the current part (int, float and sci parts of the number)
        bool neg = false;      // true if part is a negative number

        int* ret = stackalloc int[1];

        while (pos < len && (*(input + pos) > '9' || *(input + pos) < '0') && *(input + pos) != '-')
            pos++;

        // sign
        if (*(input + pos) == '-')
        {
            neg = true;
            pos++;
        }

        // integer part
        while (pos < len && !(input[pos] > '9' || input[pos] < '0'))
            part = part * 10 + (input[pos++] - '0');

        *ret = neg ? (part * -1) : part;
        return *ret;
    }

    public static unsafe float ParseFloat(char* input, int len)
    {
        //float ret = 0f;      // return value
        int pos = 0;           // read pointer position
        int part = 0;          // the current part (int, float and sci parts of the number)
        bool neg = false;      // true if part is a negative number

        float* ret = stackalloc float[1];

        // find start
        while (pos < len && (input[pos] < '0' || input[pos] > '9') && input[pos] != '-' && input[pos] != '.')
            pos++;

        // sign
        if (input[pos] == '-')
        {
            neg = true;
            pos++;
        }

        // integer part
        while (pos < len && !(input[pos] > '9' || input[pos] < '0'))
            part = part * 10 + (input[pos++] - '0');

        *ret = neg ? (float)(part * -1) : (float)part;

        // float part
        if (pos < len && input[pos] == '.')
        {
            pos++;
            double mul = 1;
            part = 0;

            while (pos < len && !(input[pos] > '9' || input[pos] < '0'))
            {
                part = part * 10 + (input[pos] - '0');
                mul *= 10; 
                pos++;
            }

            if (neg)
                *ret -= (float)part / (float)mul;
            else
                *ret += (float)part / (float)mul;

        }

        // scientific part
        if (pos < len && (input[pos] == 'e' || input[pos] == 'E'))
        {
            pos++;
            neg = (input[pos] == '-'); pos++;
            part = 0;
            while (pos < len && !(input[pos] > '9' || input[pos] < '0'))
            {
                part = part * 10 + (input[pos++] - '0');
            }

            if (neg)
                *ret /= (float)Math.Pow(10d, (double)part);
            else
                *ret *= (float)Math.Pow(10d, (double)part);
        }

        return (float)*ret;
    }
```

Comment: For those who have found this in google, although this is the chosen solution, testing highlights that this various problems:

StringToFloats calls ParseInt, not ParseFloat, always misses the last number of the string, and crashes if you specify fewer numbers than are in the string.

ParseFloat often produces very incorrect numbers, because mul overflows and becomes nonsensical. e.g. "0.000167039223" is parsed to 0.0011846202.

ParseFloat loses precision with various other numbers because intermediates are saved as floats that can't hold them exactly.

Comment: @user495625 I went ahead and undated the ParseFloat function because it was producing erratic results with higher precision numbers. The answer was to change the 'mul' variable from an int to a double. The function's precision is 10 decimal places now. I'm not going to make the rest of it bulletproof because it would lose it's illustrative usefulness. I hope you fund this answer helpful none the less. Take care.

Comment: @drankin2112 I noticed that this still trims that last digit of the input string, is there a workaround for this? I'm also attempting to use this snippet for loading models.

Comment: This is good. You may find that taking a copy of pIntBuffer and then incrementing that copy at the same time assigning to its dereference is faster than using pIntBuffer and then computing an offset. But we're talking a couple of machine code instructions fewer, not a big change.

Answer (score 1):

> So, are there built-in functions to parse directly from a substring within a string (i.e.
>   using the given start and length of a string) in order to avoid generating a temporary
>   string? If not, are there any libraries that provide efficient functions to do this?

It seems that you want to use a lexing buffer and a lexer, similar to what OCaml can provide with `ocamllex` and the `Lexbuf` buffer.  (I cannot provide references for F#.)

If your benchmark involving a huge string of integers separated by other tokens is your typical case, it will work well. But in other situations, it could be impractical.

Comment: @user2314737 What do you mean? I did not write a question!

Comment: Not really. Lexing will just copy each substring containing an int into its own string. I'd still need to parse those strings into actual ints...

Comment: @JonHarrop You are right of course.  I did not have my tea by that time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any good, but have you tried something like:

```
var stringValues = input.split(" ");

var intValues = Array.ConvertAll(stringValues, s => int.Parse(s));
```

Comment: Yes, that is even slower than the slow version because you're not only allocating temporary strings but also keeping references to them so you're paying for write barriers and the cost of the GC evacuating them from the nursery generation.

Comment: Question seems to have changed to include an F# implementation... Anyone care to translate the answer?

Comment: @JonHarrop - did you _measure_ it to be slower? By how much?

Comment: @HenkHolterman "did you *measure* it to be slower? By how much?" Yes, of course. Split and map takes 1.65s compared to 1.5s for the incremental map (code given in the question) and 0.3s for the in-line parsing (code also given in the question).

Comment: @Paddy "Anyone care to translate the answer?" How do you feel about `goto`? ;-)